# End While-Loop from another IF-Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, raspberry-pi, subprocess

i am building a Phone with my Raspberry Pi and Twinkle.
In my example i am starting Twinkle with a subprocess and checking the output for my code.

Now i need to start a while-loop when someone is calling to check the "end-call button". This works well but i need to end the loop if the far end cancelled the call. How can i break the while loop from another if condition?

Here is my code for example:

```
#IMPORTS
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading

#START TWINKLE
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["twinkle", "-c"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line

        #BUTTON WATCHER
        def button_watch():
                input_state = GPIO.input(36)
                while (input_state == False):
                        print "loop"
                        #END LOOP ON BUTTON PRESS
                        if (input_state == False):
                                print('Button Pressed')
                                input_state = GPIO.input(36)
                                GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
                                GPIO.output(32, GPIO.LOW)
                                proc.stdin.write("answer\n")
                                time.sleep(0.2)
                                break

        #INCOMING CALL
        def main():
                if (line.find("incoming call") > 0):
                        print "call is coming"
                        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                        GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
                        GPIO.output(32, GPIO.HIGH)
                        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                        GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
                        #START BUTTON WATCHER ON INCOMING CALL
                        t1 = threading.Thread(target=button_watch)
                        t1.start()


        #CALL CANCELLED
        if (line.find("far end cancelled call") > 0):
                print "call was cancelled"
                GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(32, GPIO.LOW)
                ##############################################
                # NEED TO END WHILE LOOP FROM "button_watch" #
                ##############################################


        tmain = threading.Thread(target=main)
        tmain.start()


proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Could you add more clarification as to why you have a while loop checking for the same condition as the if condition that follows?

Comment: Oh sorry that was my copy and paste. i was just testing with the code. its not necessary. i just need to break the while loop with a button click or from within the if-statement "far end cancelled call"

Comment: Not a problem. But I'd recommend you to trim down the code (edit your original question) to whatever is the closest and most accurate. This avoids more responders getting confused about the intent of the code and potentially misguiding you.

Answer (score 1):

I added a comment seeking clarification because I am not sure I understand the intent completely. Now, eventually you will find better and more robust ways to do this but the simplest solution would be to check for a compound condition (assuming you still need `input_condition == False`).

So you could define a global flag called `remote_disconnected`, initialize it in a way that your while loop runs in the beginning, and compound it like:
`while (input_condition == False and remote_disconnected == False):`

Answer (score 0):

make the button_watch depend on a global flag, so you can turn the flag to False